# Creating AD users trough Powershell activity in UiPath

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameters, automation, uipath

Im trying to create AD users with Invoke Powershell activity.

Unfortunately I am stuck with a Parameter problem.

The parameter “Name” gives following error: “The Object name has bad syntax”

The funny thing is, if I run the same powershell command directly into powershell console, I get no error.
But when the robot runs it. I get parameter error.

See screenshots for clarification.

[image: This is my parameters]

[image: This is the error box]

[image: This is the Uipath Output]

I really hope someone can crack this code, because I am pretty stuck here.

-Christian

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's too many " chars in name field? Try to change it to "Robot5" for example.

-
Egor